# Assigning a custom form error to a field in a modelform in django

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to assign a custom form error to a field in a modelform in django so that it appears where a 'standard' error such as the field being left blank, with the same formatting (which is handled by crispy forms).

My model form clean method looks like this:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(CreatorForm, self).clean()
    try:
        if cleaned_data['email'] != cleaned_data['re_email']:
            raise forms.ValidationError({'email': "Your emails don't match!"})
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return cleaned_data
```

And in my template I display the form/re-submitted form like this:

```
{{creator_form|crispy}}
```

I would like the error to appear below the re_email field if possible (though currently I thought I'd have better luck getting it below the email field. At the moment it appears at the top of the form, unformatted.

For the re_email field, despite not being part of the model, the error displayed for leaving it blank appears below the re_email field. How do I 'attach' errors to fields so they are displayed beneath/near them?

All help appreciated thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the error to display on a specific field you need to explicitly define what field the error goes on since you're overriding `.clean()`. Here is a sample taken from the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other):

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
        cc_myself = cleaned_data.get("cc_myself")
        subject = cleaned_data.get("subject")

        if cc_myself and subject and "help" not in subject:
            # We know these are not in self._errors now (see discussion
            # below).
            msg = u"Must put 'help' in subject when cc'ing yourself."
            self._errors["cc_myself"] = self.error_class([msg])
            self._errors["subject"] = self.error_class([msg])

            # These fields are no longer valid. Remove them from the
            # cleaned data.
            del cleaned_data["cc_myself"]
            del cleaned_data["subject"]

        # Always return the full collection of cleaned data.
        return cleaned_data
```